# Postgresql server and client offline mode

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, network-programming

i want to create two programs in Qt with one server and another client, my server programs insert user and customer information like fingerptint and another important data and in client users and customers use their information for working on some privacy stuff, these programs must send information on network.

so i think using Postgresql for database on server and client just connect to database and get needed information as login and etc. 
 and now this is my problems

1. my network connection must be secure no one can extract data send to
   client? (so i think postgres handle this for me, am i right?)
2. i want to client has offline mode, so i don't mind if i must setup
   another Postgresql database on client PC, and then how i can tell
   postgres update himself from server or vice versa?
3. finally whats the best solution you think?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's a bit open-ended. See https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask . Keep your questions *specific* and *focused*. Open ended I-could-write-a-book-on-this questions will get closed.

Quick version:

### my network connection must be secure no one can extract data send to client? (so i think postgres handle this for me, am i right?)

Correctly used SSL will give you one-way trust, where the client can verify the identity of the server. The server must still rely on passwords to identify the client, but it can do that over SSL.

You can use client certificates for true two-way verification.

If you're doing anything privacy sensitive consider using your own self-signed CA and distributing the CA cert through known-secure means. There are too many suborned sub-CAs signing wildcard certificates for nations to use in transparent SSL decryption for me to trust SSL CAs for things like protecting dissidents and human rights workers when they're using an Internet connection supplied or controlled by someone hostile to them.

Don't take my word on this; read up on it carefully.

### i want to client has offline mode, so i don't mind if i must setup another Postgresql database on client PC, and then how i can tell postgres update himself from server or vice versa?

It sounds like you want asynchronous replication with intermittent connections.

This is hard. I recommend doing it at the application level where you can implement application-specific sync schedules and conflict resolution logic. You can use trigger maintained change-list tables to keep a record of what changed since the DBs last saw each other. Don't use timestamps to keep in sync, as they clock drift between server and client will cause you to miss changes. You might want to use something like the pgq ticker on the master DB.

### finally whats the best solution you think?

Too open ended, not enough info provided to even start to answer.

Comment: Tanks a lot, your right sorry for open ended problem, any way can i save a backup database on client and then open it from postgresql server and client simultaneously?

Comment: @DanielNor No, there is not. I don't even understand how that could begin to work.